# Pushing Jersey ContainerRequest and ContainerResponse data logs together to a data store

Tags: logging, filter, jersey

We're currently using `Jersey` OAuth filter. The requirement is that we need to push `ContainerRequest` and `ContainerResponse` datagrams (and any exceptions if applicable) together to a third-party data store which provides a `push` API which works asynchronously. I've read about `ContainerRequestFilters` and `ContainerResponseFilters` interfaces and `LoggingFilter` (which uses a `Logger` to write data to). Instead of making two `push` calls to send request and response datagram separately, I would like to combine that into a single call. I see that `ContainerResponseFilters` takes both `ContainerRequest` and `ContainerResponse`, so is it feasible and good to implement that interface to push this data together. Will that work even when OAuth filter throws some other exception? Are there any other better alternatives?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Answering for the sake of others,

AFAIK, there is no straightforward way to have both the request and response data together as `ContainerRequestFilters` implementation deals with the `ContainerRequest` and reads the input stream and `ContainerResponseFilters` implementation deals with the `ContainerResponse` object. One can still access the request headers in the `filter` method of `ContainerResponseFilters` implementation, but not the entity. I had to use the properties map (which seems to be mutable) as a temporary map to put request entity and retrieve that in the response filter. It looks like a dirty hack, but I didn't find any other way.

Comment: Downvoter(s): Please explain what's wrong (and how it should be corrected) so the readers (including myself) will benefit.